# how to not call viewdidload in uinavigationcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am looking for a solution to my situation. My app is as followed:

On VC1 there is a textfield and button. User types a name. Then click on a button. This button open VC2. User gives additional information in VC2 then press save. I used a segue to go back to VC1 and transfer those additional information as a string to VC1. But in VC1 viewdidload has called and due to that information in the textfield is deleted!!! How can I navigate between VC without recalling viewdidload?

I found some information about singleton objects. If I can define an object which is alive during time I go through VCs would be great. How can I have an object with multiple fields and alive all the time.

Comment: I cannot understand your question clearly. Can you post your code here?

Comment: how are you showing VC2?

Comment: please if any of the answers helped you , up vote it or marked as answer ..

Comment: ArtusOlszak gave the correct answer, but you should really put some time into reading this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/

Comment: Question isn't clear enough and no existing code provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that why you are using push segue to move back.

Here you need to assing a push segue from VC-A to VC-B and name its     identifier like moveForward and button press call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"moveForward" sender:self];
```

and if any information u want to pass to VC-B pass it in this method

```
 - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"moveForward"])
    {
        VC-B* vcObject=[segue destinationViewController];

        //vcObject.info = your info//etc
    }
   }
```

In a same way when u have to return to VC-A from VC-B assign a rewind segue from VC-B to VC-A and name its identifier like moveBack and on button press 
and do the above mention method in VC-B too.

Answer (score 2):

viewDidLoad method is called only once per lifecycle of UIViewController, so most probably you are creating somehow new VC1. You need keep reference to first VC1 and go back to that view controller.

To navigate using UINavigationController use those methods:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2];

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

(call them inside VC1 / VC2)

Answer (score -1):

here is how you can define singleton class that is called AppShareData :
AppShareData.h

```
@interface AppSharedData : NSObject
+(AppSharedData*)sharedInstance ;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL sharedBoolVariable ;
@end
```

AppShareData.m:

```
@implementation AppSharedData
@synthesize sharedBoolVariable;
+(AppSharedData *) sharedInstance
{
   static AppSharedData *_sharedInstance = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t Token;
   dispatch_once(&Token, ^{
     _sharedInstance = [[AppSharedData alloc]init];
   });
  return _sharedInstance;
}
@end
```

and then if you want to edit or set the value of the variable in any class i would do the following :

```
-(void)editMethod
{
   AppSharedData * dataObject = [AppSharedData sharedInstance] ; 
   dataObject = YES ; 
}
```

and if i want to retrieve the value of the variable in any class i do the following :

```
-(void)retrieveMethod
{
   AppSharedData * dataObject = [AppSharedData sharedInstance] ; 
   BOOL someVariableInMyClass = [dataObject sharedBoolVariable] ; 
}
```