# Swift 1.2 - prepareForSegue targeting a View Controller embedded Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift

As in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788416/swift-prepareforsegue-with-navigation-controller) question, I need to pass a value from a ViewController to another one, the second VC is embedded in navigation controller. I tried the answer to that question but **value printed in console is always nil**. Can't figure out what to do.

In First VC I have:

```
var dataToSend : String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "toSecondVCSegue" {

            println("prepareForSegue occurred test value is: *\(dataToSend)*")

            let destinationNavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let targetController = destinationNavigationController.topViewController as! SecondViewController

            targetController.receivedTest = dataToSend

        }
    }




    @IBAction func toSecondVCButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("toSecondVCSegue", sender: nil)

        dataToSend = "passed"
    }
```

in the second I have:

```
var receivedTest : String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println("in SecondViewController in viewDidLoad receivedTest is: *\(receivedTest)*")

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        println("in SecondViewController in viewWillAppear receivedTest is: *\(receivedTest)*")

    }


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        println("in SecondViewController in viewDidAppear receivedTest is: *\(receivedTest)*")

    }
```

Comment: after posting question I realized, wrong order in the button func, perform segue should be the last statement :( now it works!, maybe you can help me another way, do you think I should call a super. in the viewWillAppear  viewDidAppear?

Comment: Yes, super must be there. There are rare situations when you need to avoid using super in these methods. It will be like super.viewWillAppear(animated)

Comment: but if I write override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) I got an error :(

Comment: Inside viewWillAppear: you need to call super.viewWillAppear, inside viewDidAppear: need to call super.viewDidAppear:

Comment: so, this is wrong?  `override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear`

Comment: Provide error. It should be like `override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) { super.viewWillAppear(animated) }`

Comment: I have answer this question in objectiveC you can easily convert it into swift have a look on the concept http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264264/how-to-not-call-viewdidload-in-uinavigationcontroller/32266115#32266115

Answer (score 1):

I think, the reason is you set value to `dataToSend` variable **after** calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` and so it stays always nil

Try changing your code as :

```
@IBAction func toSecondVCButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    dataToSend = "passed"
    performSegueWithIdentifier("toSecondVCSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

This may help!

Comment: figured out after asking :) but have a bonus question, do you think I should call a super. in the viewWillAppear viewDidAppear? how to do it?

Comment: I dont understand your bonus question.