# Load information from previous ViewControllers swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Picture]

I think we all have been through problems in `Swift`. I wasn't able to find the correct answer for my question. I've tried over and over again.

I've represented an image where it explains how our app should works.

Users can select an option per view. So in a last one the `Labels` will change depending of each choose.

I hope you can give me a hand with that guys. Thanks

class ViewController1: `UIViewController` {

```
@IBOutlet weak var colorLabelSelected: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var nextOutlet: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    nextOutlet.hidden = true



}


@IBAction func greenButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    colorLabelSelected.text = "You have selected a green BG color"
    nextOutlet.hidden = false


}


@IBAction func blueButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    colorLabelSelected.text = "You have selected a blue BG color"
    nextOutlet.hidden = false

}


@IBAction func pinkButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    colorLabelSelected.text = "You have selected a pink BG color"
    nextOutlet.hidden = false

}
```

}

`ViewController` 2 and `ViewController` 3 are like `ViewController` 1

And I have created a .`swift` class called Attributes but It's empty for now.

I don't know how to make this work.

Comment: Check answer here as it is in objectiveC but you will get a hand on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264264/how-to-not-call-viewdidload-in-uinavigationcontroller/32266115#32266115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `prepareForSegue`for your concept

for example

```
@IBAction func pinkButton(sender: AnyObject) {

colorLabelSelected.text = "You have selected a pink BG color"
nextOutlet.hidden = false

self.performSegueWithIdentifier("thirdController", sender: self)

}



override func prepareForSegue(segue:(UIStoryboardSegue!), sender:AnyObject!)
{
if (segue.identifier == "thirdController")
    {
    var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as! thirdController
    print("i set the loading thingy")
    svc.toPass = colorLabelSelected.text
    }
}
```

**ThirdViewController**

create the global variable like

```
  var toPass:String!
```

for tutorial reference see this [link](http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/)

Comment: Thx so much Anbu!!! What if we want to pass the same value to more than one View?

Comment: then you need to use "Protocol" or singleton class or local DB , or Bean object class or use Appdelegate Shared preference methods

Comment: see this example for how to use the singleton class in swift --http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80246/swift-1-2-singleton-implementation

Answer (score 1):

When you push your next `viewController`, override `prepareForSegue` method, get reference to your destinationViewController and pass to it information you need. This will help pass that data around.
Or create a singleton object, some kind of model, where you write the value user has selected on the first screen, and then on the second screen - you read the data from that singleton object.

Comment: How do I create a singleton object? Which is best? Thx

Comment: singletons are global so probably not a very good programming habit. I'd say prepareforsegue is better and also the most common way

Comment: I'll add an answer on how you use the method

Answer (score 1):

Define your model, for example:

```
    class MyData {

        var background = UIColor()
        var title = ""
        var level = ""
    }
```

Use appDelegate. In AppDelegate.swift,

```
    var myData = MyData()
```

In other screens, for instance first screen, use

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.myData.background = yourColor
```

Same to others

Answer (score 0):

*you have to create array and create one property of array in second and third class and pass color in secondviewcontroller and in secondviewcontroller add title in array of property and pass it to thirdviewcontroller
you can easily manage using create property.*